# Archive page showing wrong month

Tags: archives

My site's archive page is echoing wrong Month name. Though the URL is `2012/11/`, it's echoing the month `December 2012`.

I found nothing wrong with the code:

```
<?php
if ( is_day() ) :
printf( __( 'Daywise Posts: %s', 'theme-name' ), '<span id="font">' . "<b><i>". get_the_date() . "</b></i>" .  '</span>' );
elseif ( is_month() ) :
printf( __( 'Month-wise Posts: %s', 'theme-name' ), '<span id="font">' . "<b><i>". get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'theme-name' ) ) . "</b></i>".  '</span>' );
elseif ( is_year() ) :
printf( __( 'Year-wise Posts: %s', 'theme-name' ), '<span id="font">' . "<b><i>" . get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'theme-name' ) ) . "</b></i>".  '</span>' );
else :
_e( 'Archives', 'theme-name' );
endif;
?>
```

It's WordPress 3.4.2 here.

Comment: Do you use `query_posts()` on that page, in a widget or some other code?

Comment: No, I din't use any `query_posts()`, I've learned its problems from a stackexchange [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts.) Wherever I needed a query, I used `WP_Query()`.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/aNtcBUcC) is my whole bunch of code for `Archive.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following above the first if statement to see what actual day is being useddisplayed:

```
echo get_the_date();
```

It might also help to add the following lines to help debug exactly what the query is doing:

```
global $wp_query;
var_dump($wp_query);
```

The code is correct - so it has to be something else affecting the display.  Does it do this for every month or just specific ones?

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. The date I always get is "26 December 2012" even if I am in "24 November 2012". Same, when I'm in "November 2012", the date echoing is "December 2012". Thing seems to me is that, "26 December 2012" is somewhere stacked default. I've seen all the posts and the very first post I got is of "2012/11/24". Here is the site where I'm working: [link](http://www.news4.com.bd/2012/11/24/). The date showing in the `<title></title>` tag is showing correctly.

Comment: The `$wp_query()`; is showing: `object(WP_Query)#598 (47) { ["query_vars"]=> array(55) { ["year"]=> int(2012) ["monthnum"]=> int(11) ["day"]=> int(24)`, but still the date echoing is `December 26, 2012`.

Comment: What are the dates on the posts that are showing?  Is there a post from Nov 24?

Comment: I hid the date from the posts. But I tested that the post showing is correct, according to the URL. And the wp_query thing I pasted here is from 24th Nov's archive. So it's echoing the date 24 Nov. That means the query executing is working correctly, but the echoing is not right.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that your header template includes an extra loop or something like that.

Try adding this above the first if:
    wp_reset_query();

Comment: right you are. got the WP_Query(); without the reset, and the problem is solved. Thanks a lot, brother.